# Starting sshd automatically if it is down/failed

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, cron

I am trying to create a Bash .sh script for a cronjob that starts the OpenSSH server if it is down or failed.

Last night the SSH server was down and when I tried to access it today (from work) the connection was refused ofc.
No traces in the /var/log/messages for the failure.

So the question is - **how to determine is sshd running so if it is not to "sudo service ssh start" it?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds fishy. Trying to "fix" something without understanding the cause _never_ is a good idea.

Comment: does your system have systemd? The log files might be seen with journalctl.

Comment: Nah, the system does not have the systemd nor journalctl

Comment: make sure that the sshd server will not crash

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/45055/using-inittab-to-ensure-sshd-and-other-important-items-are-still-running-an

Answer (score 4):

Fellas, I believe that I have managed to do the task:

```
#!/bin/bash
service="ssh"

if (( ! $(sudo service ssh status | cut -d" " -f 3 | cut -d"." -f 1) == "running" ))
then
        sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
fi
```

I have changed the LogLevel to Verbose, I hope the next time I will track more clues regarding the failure of the sshd.

Answer (score 2):

I'm implementing the following:

```
[ $(sudo service ssh status | grep running | grep -v grep | wc -l) == 0 ] && sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

Answer (score 0):

as other people said It's Incorrect to start it without finding what caused this problem, but I wrote some help for the script you want

1. first you should check the status of your openssh server for example:

> ps -aux | grep ssh

1. then write an if to check if it is down or not

   you can check it with the result of previous step.
2. if that was down, start it

> sudo service ssh start

Comment: I was thinking of:
ps -aux | grep ssh | wc -l

But this outputs different outputs, depending on how many connections are there to the SSH server.